# Find $\mathrm E \eta$ where $\eta = min(\xi_1^3, \xi_2^2)$ is random variable

Tags: probability

I have a probability problem about random variables.

Need to find $\mathrm E\eta$. $\eta = min(\xi_1^3, \xi_2^2)$. 
$\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are independent random variables and have a exponential distribution with parameter 1.

Could you help me please?

Also, how to solve this kind of problems when I need to find expected value of several random variables? Is there a great way to do it?

Comment: Sorry. I mean exponential distribution. E — expected value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notation: $a \wedge b := \min\{a ,b\}$.
Since $\xi_1,\xi_2$ are independent,
$$
P( \xi_1^3 \wedge \xi_2^2 > t) = P( \xi_1^3 > t, \xi_2^2 > t) = P(\xi_1^3 > t) P(\xi_2^2 > t) = P(\xi_1 > t^{1/3}) P(\xi_2 > t^{1/2})
$$
$$
= e^{-t^{1/3}} e^{-t^{1/2}} = e^{-(t^{1/3}+t^{1/2})}
$$
Then use that $$E\eta = \int_0^\infty P(\eta\geq t)dt =\int_0^\infty e^{-(t^{1/3}+t^{1/2})}dt. $$

You can now use a computer to numerically approximate.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I can't understand why $P(min(\xi_1^3, \xi_2^2) > t) = P(\xi_1^3 > t, \xi_2^2 > t)$?

Comment: The minimum of $a,b$ is bigger than $t$ if and only if both $a$ and $b$ are bigger than $t$.

Comment: Oh, it is really simple. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to proceed. On the plus side, one can derive the exact symbolic answer quite easily with a computer algebra system. On the downside, the solution to the expectation does not appear to have a nice compact form. To illustrate, if $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are independent standard Exponentials, then the joint pdf of $(\xi_1, \xi_2)$ is:

[image]

We seek:  $E[min(\xi_1^3, \xi_2^2)]$

[image]

All done. To 5 decimal places, the latter is:   0.55248

**Notes**

1. The `Expect` function used above is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.
2. For more detail on the special functions in the output, see: [AiryBi](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AiryBi.html) and[HypergeometricPFQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html)